# Can't ping Linux IPv6 bridge from host

Tags: linux, ipv6, bridge

I'm using a Linux box with two network interfaces as bridge (`br0`) and one system (`X`)  behind the bridge with its own IPv6 address configured. Its other end is connected to a router.

The bridge interface (`br0`) also has an IPv6 address configured. I am able to ping my router from `X`, but not able to ping `br0`. Similarly, I'm not able to ping `X` from `br0`.

I created a packet dump and saw neighbor solicitation and neighbor advertisement from both ends, but it's not getting updated in `ip neigh show` as `REACHABLE`. I'm unable to understand what's going on, since I'm not proficient with networking

Do I have to do anything to resolve this issue?